# Ruby Classes Confusion

Tags: ruby, class, variables

I'm kind of stumped at the workings of a Ruby class. I understand everything that is going on inside of the class here, but it's the variable assignment and calling of the class that confuses me.

```
class BankAccount

def initialize(name)
    @transactions = []
    @balance = 0 #
end

def deposit
    print "How much would you like to deposit?"
    amount = gets.chomp
    @balance += amount.to_f
    puts "$#{amount} deposited."
end

def show_balance
    puts "Your balance is #{@balance}."
end

end

bank_account = BankAccount.new("James Dean")
bank_account.class

bank_account.deposit
bank_account.show_balance
```

When we did...

```
   bank_account = BankAccount.new("James Dean")
```

... it seems as though whenever I call bank_account, it will use the .new method (which I am lead to believe activates the initialize method) to create a new account with the given name.

Then, from what I understand when we call .class on bank_account, it just outputs the class type.

But, next we call bank_account.deposit. Although, I'm under the impression that whenever we call bank_account now, it will create a new account using the BankAccount class... So by doing bank_account.deposit, what I envision it is actually doing is:

```
BankAccount.new("James Dean").deposit
```

So if I make two deposits (or even use bank_account.show_balance), then from my understanding, it will be creating a new account with the name James Dean over and over and over, every time I use the bank_account variable. (Because bank_account = BankAccount.new)

Can anyone help me clear this up and understand it a bit better?

**Also**, just on a side note, could we ever use:

```
BankAccount.new(gets.chomp)
```

so that we could create new account with names according to user input?

(Thanks everyone. This is my third question and my former two have apparently been posted in the wrong places. -_- Hoping I got this one right.)

Comment: `BankAccount.new(gets.chomp)` - can, but shouldn't

Answer (score 3):

> Although, I'm under the impression that whenever we call bank_account now, it will create a new account using the BankAccount class.

That's not right. Your code only calls `BankAccount.new` *once*. The result is assigned to `bank_account`. Each time you access `bank_account`, you're accessing the constructed object created on the first line.

When you write `x = Y.new`, you're not assigning the expression `Y.new` to `x`, you're *evaluating* the expression `Y.new` and assigning the *result* to `x`.

Similarly, if you write `x = my_function()`, the function is evaluated and the result is assigned to `x`; any references to `x` from this point are completely decoupled from the function.